# Accelerometer Values Android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an Android application and I am working with accelerometer values. I used this method

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    System.out.println("X: " + event.values[0]);
    System.out.println("Y: " + event.values[1]);
    System.out.println("Z: " + event.values[2]);
}
```

My values seem to vary from -10 to 10. In my application I need to use a [dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) which contains both triaxial acceleration from the accelerometer (total acceleration) and the estimated body acceleration. However both values seem to vary from -1 to 1 and therefore don't match my values at all. Can you tell me how can I transform my values to match those of the dataset (so that I can compare them) and which acceleration do I need to use, the body or the total acceleration please?

Comment: From the API doc **All values are in SI units (m/s^2).** So just divide by 9.81 m/s^2 and you scaled your data, it will be -1 and 1. The rest of question is off-topic.

Comment: It isn't exactly from -1 to 1. At times, the value is slightly larger than 1 or slightly smaller than -1. And what is the difference between body and total acceleration please? The dataset contains both and I don't know which one shall I use